# How can I print 404 requests in Django?

Tags: django

I have a Django app and that work perfect, I want get all request 404 for print in terminal.
like: `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/hello # result is 404 because I haven't this URL` I want get `/admin/hello` because I haven't this URL.
How can I do?

I mean :
User enter `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/hello` then terminal   set a= `/admin/hello` and print(a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a middleware for this. Here is an example based on [**`BrokenLinkEmailMiddleware`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/common.py#L118) implementation:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class BrokenLinkMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if response.status_code == 404 and not settings.DEBUG:  # for production
            domain = request.get_host()
            path = request.get_full_path()
            referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')

            if not self.is_ignorable_request(request, path, domain, referer):
                ua = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '<none>')
                ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '<none>')
                # Store response in Database
                YourModel.objects.create(domain=domain, path=path, ua=ua, ip=ip, referer=referer)
        return response
```

And add it your settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
   ...
   'path.to.BrokenLinkMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: when I   enter in setting `'path.to.BrokenLinkMiddleware',` i get error   No module named 'path'

Comment: Ok I Understand. 'path.to.BrokenLinkMiddleware' is   'nameap.views.BrokenLinkMiddleware'  and work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks from @ruddra for answer.

I explain simple:

I add to views.py:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class BrokenLinkMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if response.status_code == 404  :  # for production
            domain = request.get_host()
            path = request.get_full_path()
            print('path : ',path)
            # print('domain : ',domain)

            ua = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '<none>')
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '<none>')
            # Store response in Database
            # print('ua:',ua)
            # print('ip:',ip)
        return response
```

Then add to settings.py segment MIDDLEWARE :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
'MynameAPP.views.BrokenLinkMiddleware'  
...
]
```

And finish work. thanks again  @ruddra.